# SQL Alchemy Query IN using python list

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Im tryng to use a python list from a dataframe using sqlachemy 2.0. But its not working as expected.

my code:

```
Lista1 = DFAC1['xd'].to_list()

Query = select(CRM_Table.c.xd,CRM_Table.c.SEGMENTO_HOMO).where(CRM_Table.c.xd.in_(Lista1))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    DFSegmento = pd.read_sql(Query, conn)
```

My error:

```
"name": "DBAPIError",
      "message": "(pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')\n[SQL: SELECT [DBM_DATAMART].dbo.[CRM].[xd], [DBM_DATAMART].dbo.[CRM].[SEGMENTO_HOMO] \nFROM [DBM_DATAMART].dbo.[CRM] \nWHERE [DBM_DATAMART].dbo.[CRM].[xd] IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
```

PD: the list have around 5000 values